# Filter data for genres (with a select) in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vue-router, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel api.php routes and I need to filter musicians based on their common genre, so after the select is clicked I want to switch page and go to a page where I've got all the musicians with the choosed genre.

The problem is, no matter which genre I choose from the select, it always get me back the same three musicists, and I don't know how to get that id to pass in the filter function.

ps: for now I'm just showing the musicians in the same page, but the final result should be shown in a different page, as I mentioned above.

Here's my code:

ExampleComponent.vue is as following, here I've got problems to find the id to pass as an argument in the filter() function.

```
<template>
    
        <div class="jumbotron bg-jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h1 class="headline">Playing the mood</h1>
                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select @change="filter(1)" class="form-control mb-2" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option :value="genre.id" v-for="genre in genres" :key="genre.id">{{ genre.name }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-for="musician in musicians" :key="musician.id">
                        {{ musician.stagename }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/jumboimg.png" alt="Jumbtron">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ExampleComponent',

        data() {
            return {
                genres: [],
                musicians: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getGenres() {
                axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/genres')
                .then( res => {
                    this.genres = res.data;
                    // console.log( this.genres )
                    
                })
                .catch( err => {
                    console.log( err )
                })
            },

            filter(id) {
                axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filter/${id}`)
                .then( res => {
                    res.data.forEach( el => {
                        this.musicians = el.musicians
                    })
                    console.log( this.musicians )
                })
                .catch( err => {
                    console.log( err )
                })
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getGenres()
            // this.filter(this.$routes.params.id)
        }
    }
</script>
```

The api.php routes

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::namespace('Api')->group( function() {

    Route::get('/genres', 'GenreController@index');
    Route::get('/filter/{id}', 'GenreController@filter');
});
```

The GenreController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Genre;

class GenreController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        $genres = Genre::all();

        return response()->json($genres);
    }

    public function filter($id) {
        

        $genres = Genre::where('id', $id)->with('musicians')->get();

        return response()->json($genres);
    }
}
```

The Musician Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Musician extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 
        'stagename',
        'slug', 
        'description',
        'bio',
        'services',
        'typology',
        'cover'
    ]; 

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User'); 
    }

    public function genres() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre'); 
    }
```

The Genre Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Genre extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'slug'
    ]; 

    public function musicians() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Musician'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter method in `GenreController`  must returns musicians while you are returning `$genres`, I think your filter method should be like this (taking into account that the relation between musicians and genres):

```
public function filter($id) {

  $musicians = Musician::whereHas('genres', function($query) use ($id) {
    $query>where('id', '=', $id);
  })->get();
    
    return response()->json($musicians );
}
```

and in your vue component just log the result for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filter/${id}`
to make sure what response you get from the url.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a genre_id foreign key, cause there's a pivot table (genre_musician) where all genres are associated to the relative musician. So how do I get that genre_id from the pivot?

Comment: Please check the edits for my answer, I think it should works now

Answer (score 0):

you are manually passing the id if 1 to filter(1)

Try applying a v-model to the select(input binding).
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select @change="filter()"  v-model="filter_id" class="form-control mb-2" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                            <option:value="genre.id" v-for="genre in genres" :key="genre.id">{{ genre.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

//data

```
    data() {
        return {
            genres: [],
            musicians: [],
            filter_id:null
        }
    },
```

// methods

```
filter() {
                axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filter/${this->filter_id}`)
                .then( res => {
                    res.data.forEach( el => {
                        this.musicians = el.musicians
                    })
                    console.log( this.musicians )
                })
                .catch( err => {
                    console.log( err )
                })
            }
```

The idea here being that you have a piece of dynamic data "filter_id" that is bound to the value of the select input and then passed to your axois call.

I also believe you can update your request controller to clean it up a bit using a

```
$musicians = App\Modles\Musician::with(['genere' => function ($query)  use ($id) {
    $query->whereId($id);
}])->get();
```

then in axios (vue) you can just use this.musicians = response.data  and avoid the foreach loop.

Comment: I've tried just now, could be a fix for the Vue part, but in Laravel I still have to catch that foreign key (genre_id) from the genre_musician pivot table. Otherwise it will always return the same three musicians.

Comment: `$musicians= Musician::whereHas('generes', function($q) use($id) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $id);
})->get();`   $id being the v-model filter_id of genere you passs as a param

Comment: It didn't work, I think that finding a way to get that id in the filter() function will solve the problem, but how?

Comment: I posted how above,  you need to v-model and bind the id to the select  and then pass it in axios

Comment: Solved, I just put the v-model as you said, but mantaining the same asset as before, passing the v-model in the filter function, thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: I was missing the argument (the v-model) inside the @change="filter()", now it's ok! ;)

Comment: nice,  now that you are getting the id, you may be able to change your vue response from axios and avoid the foreach loop and just use this.musicians = res.data     check your console.log response and see what it gives.